# Not able to launch the uiAutomatorViewer from my windows 10 :: Getting -Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported. Use -classpath instead

Tags: windows-10, uiautomatorviewer

I am not able to launch the uiautomatorviewer from My windows 10. I am using JAVA version 15.

```
C:\Users\Bhavya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can someone please suggest what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to launch the UI Automator after downgrading the installed java version to my system .

To launch the UI Automator successfully, we need to run Java 8 .